# How to get the element data type of an Allocation in RenderScript?

Tags: android, renderscript

For example, I created an `Allocation` by

```
Allocation alloc = Allocation.createTyped(mRs, anotherAlloc.getType());
```

Then, I want to know the data type of the Elements in `alloc`. However, when I call `alloc.getElement().getDataType()`, it returns `null`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the Type of anotherAlloc? Also, do you mean null or DataType.NONE. If anotherAlloc is a user-defined Type, it will be NONE, but DataKind will be USER.

Comment: I tried to create anotherAlloc from a Bitmap. I think the type of anotherAlloc should be UNSIGNED_8. However, both anotherAlloc.getElement().getDataType() and alloc.getElement().getDataType() return null. I mean null but not none here.